# Offline installing the downloaded IPS package files using OpenIndiana `pkg` (or Solaris 11)

Tags: openindiana

I'm gonna write a script to pull down the [package files](https://serverfault.com/questions/348139/how-to-manually-download-individual-files-from-the-openindiana-or-solaris-pkg), now how can I install them?

Can I get `pkg` to use a `file://` URL instead of an `http://` URL?

Alternatively, Is there a better format to do this with? For example, can a stand-alone `pkg` file be created, given [the manifest](http://pkg.openindiana.org/dev/manifest/0/developer%2Fbuild%2Fmake%400.5.11%2C5.11-0.151.1%3A20110912T022544Z), and all the individual files?

In case you wondered, I do not want to create a mirror of the repo.

Comment: Wish I could tell you, can't get the damn thing to get past the "dots" in a Virtualbox guest :/

Comment: Took me awhile to figure out what you meant. :) (To those who don't know, that is when attempting to boot to a Solaris image, there are dots while it reads in the OS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to point to [my answer](https://serverfault.com/a/348265/90132) on your other post. You can set up a `pkg.depotd` instance locally and add that as a publisher, but `pkg` cannot install directly from the filesystem. This is mostly because the package server provides extra metadata as well as the `pkg search` functionality.

The local pkg server doesn't have to be a complete mirror. As I said in the other post, pkgrecv can just pull down what you want (and its dependencies).